# Section background image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have a section set up like this:

```
<section id="fullpage">

</section>

html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#fullpage { 
    background-image: url("sakura.png");
}
```

I have the sakura.png in the root directory but the image does not show up, I only see a white screen, what could be the problem?

**Edit: I had to remove the quotes from background-image: url("sakura.png");**

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder, background-color does work but images keep failing

Comment: Do you have file "sakura.png" in the same directory, as the file with this code section?

Comment: Your question is looks like duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading. Please check answers there, I think that removing quotes can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Background image not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
html, body {height: 100%}

#fullpage {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('sakura.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="fullpage"></section>
```

Also works like this:

- `#fullpage {height: 100vh}`
- `html, body {width: 100vw; height: 100vh}` and `#fullpage {height: 100%}`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a height to section.

```
#fullpage { 
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url("sakura.png");
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me :/ background-color does work but I images keep failing

Comment: This should work as it does for me, is this css written in a external file, and is there a console error for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a width property to your #fullpage

```
#fullpage { 
     width:100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-image: url("sakura.png");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding / to the url like so:

```
#fullpage { 
    background-image: url("/sakura.png");
}
```

Also try adding a height/width to your section.