# Is there another way to set background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem adding the `background-image: url()` tag to my code. It doesn't display. I've tried everything, added strings, made it the first in the block but nothing works. Quite frustrating.

The HTML:

```
<div id="home" class="offset">
      <div class="landing">
        <div class="home-wrap">
          <div class="home-inner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.home-inner {
  background-image: url("imgs\04-full.jpg");
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21374697/14481766

Answer (score 2):

This is happening becouse the `div` with the `background-image` attribute has no sizes so it is displayed in the html page but it has width and heght null.

```css
.home-inner {
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/062021b6a1aae23a9651e9ab01ec9e36?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 500px; /* fixed width */
  height: 500px;  /* fixed height */
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="offset">
      <div class="landing">
        <div class="home-wrap">
          <div class="home-inner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Try adding some content to it or giving the div some `width` and `height`