# CSS background image won't show up

Tags: css

So my header image shows up when I open Chrome from my code editor (webstorm) but after I close webstorm and open index.html manually from my project folder, the header image won't load/show up,   `background-image: url("/assets/heroimage.jpg");` any idea why?
Same problem on github when I host my website

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a "relative path" adding a point at the start?

```
background-image: url("./assets/heroimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading) the problem is with how you linking the image to the CSS.

Try removing double quotes and removing unnecessary backslash:
`background-image: url(assets/heroimage.jpg);`
or
`background-image: url(./assets/heroimage.jpg);`

Hope it helps :)