# BackgroundImage inline style is not working in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

the path to the image is correct, but it is not inserted correctly into the html

`` {backgroundImage: `url('${getContentPath()}${PATH_SEP}${pdf.cover}')`} ``[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use absolute paths. Or put the image in the `public` folder and refer by URL. And don't use cyrillic for folder's name!
(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-background-image-tutorial-how-to-set-backgroundimage-with-inline-css-style/)